# Do you need both childs beds to adopt one child?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

i only want to adopt one child in the game Skyrim, but im not sure if i need both beds in the bedroom add on to adopt one

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need both beds and the chests in the children's bedroom to adopt. See [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108713/why-cant-i-adopt-children-despite-having-a-steading-in-falkreath) answer for more details.