# Hearthfire bugs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I'm playing Skyrim on PS3 and bought every property available in the hearthfire expansion. I have one fully decked out manor near Solitude and one south of DawnStar livable but according to General Stats (pause menu) I only own one house; the Than Breezehome house in Whiterun. I even got the Land Owner trophy for buying all properties. The Manor east of Solitude has bedrooms and all but I am not getting the dialog option when I speak with my adopted daughter to move to any property.

Is this common or fixable? How could I have a fully built manor, another with the small cottage setup and only have 1 home according to game stats?

Comment: This might be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the article on owned houses in Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses), the Hearthfire plots do not count towards the number of houses owned in the game statistics. This is probably because when you buy the property, it is technically not a house, just land. It is not listed as a bug, so it should be considered normal behavior. Whether this can be "fixed" or not on a gaming console depends on the software developers.

However, your basic question, "Why can't I move my children into a Hearthfire home?" is a duplicate. [See this answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108713/why-cant-i-adopt-children-despite-having-a-steading-in-falkreath). In particular, you need to build two children's beds and two children's chests, even when you only have one child, and you need extra beds for your house carl or steward. If you don't have enough beds in a particular player-built manor it won't appear as an option.

Comment: All the reports I've read concerning Hearthfire home bigs say you have to own more than one home to move family to a self-built manor. If the manors don't count why would that even be an issue and does this mean those on consoles can't move family to any hearthfire homes? I've had the same issue even when I owned a home in all major cities in each hold. They could move from Thane-homes but never had Hearthfire homes as an option.

Comment: I've never heard of the restriction on minimum number of homes owned before you can move a family in, so I can't answer that. I've only heard about the requirements for beds and chests. I've moved my wife and two kids to Lakeview, so I'm sure it's possible to move families on the PC. I assume it's the same on consoles, but a console player will have to confirm.

Comment: After doing a ton of research only one option is left that seems viable. Apparently in Hearthfire houses the workbenches tag the house as "under construction" so until all of the workbenches are removed, then nobody can move in. I haven't confirmed this yet but when I do I'll come back and post either way. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I still have the workbenches in my family's house, so I believe that is incorrect. But it sounds like you've asked the wrong question. Are you having a problem moving a family in? You might want to edit your question to reflect that. Which house wings are built? What furniture has been added? Who is already living in the house (house carl, steward?) And what options appear when you speak to your spouse?

Comment: Actually, your question is probably a duplicate. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.